# CSS Horizontal Menu with centered Horizontal submenus

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a horizontal menu with vertical submenus, but I would like to make the dropdown submenus horizontal as well.  I have been trying to accomplish this for days with no luck.  Here is an example  http://jsfiddle.net/bukYf/  Here is the CSS for my menus..

```
/* Navigation Menu Styles */
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 7px 6px 0;

    line-height: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}


/* main level link */
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #65a7ed;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: block;
    padding:  8px 10px;
    margin: 0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.6em;

}
#nav a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
}

/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: #65a7ed url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 1px #f8f8f8;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .2);


}

/* sub levels link hover */
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: #666;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    background: #0078ff url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
    color: #fff !important;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;

    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    display: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    background: #b6d1ee url(img/gradient.png) repeat-x 0 0;
    border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
    left: 61px;
    top: -3px;
}

/* rounded corners of first and last link */
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 9px;

    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 9px;
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 9px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 9px;
}

/* clearfix */
#nav:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#nav {
    display: inline-block;
} 
html[xmlns] #nav {
    display: block;
}

* html #nav {
    height: 1%;
}
```

I'm sure the answer is simple I just haven't been able to accomplish it.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ and http://jsfiddle.net, don't expect us to grab a buttload of CSS, think up the HTML ourselves and then see if we can reproduce your problem. It's a Q&A site - and the A's only come when the Q's are quickly digestable.

Comment: I apologize, I've edited the question and included the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

*is very important to put the. html*

**css**

```
#menu {
    background: #222;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#222, #555);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#22, #555);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#222, #555);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#222, #555);
    background: linear-gradient(#222, #555);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
#v {
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:10px;
}
#sub {
    width:85px;
    background:#ccc;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    margin-top:10px;
}
a {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:1.3em;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:8px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.4em;
}
a:hover {
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#v:hover #sub {
    display:block;
}
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avril_alejandro/GPfQA/)

Comment: is very easy to make a horizontal or vertical menu

Comment: That's not even remotely close to what I was looking for.